# Is it guaranteed that a specialization of std::numeric_limits<T> for user-defined numeric type S works for cv-qualified S out of the box?

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I have a user-defined numeric type `S` for which I specialized `std::numeric_limits<T>`.

Although I specialized for `S` only, my custom `max()` is also used for cv-qualified `S`, at least with recent versions of gcc and MSVC.

Is this guaranteed to work, or am I relying on an implementation detail here?

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

// Some user-defined numeric type,
// for which I'd like to specialize std::numeric_limits<T>.
struct S {};

namespace std
{
    // My specialization, for brevity providing only max()
    template <>
    struct numeric_limits<S>
    {
        static /*constexpr*/ S max()
        {
            std::cout << "got called" << '\n';
            return S();
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    // Although I specialize for S only, my custom max() is also used for cv-qualified S.
    // Is this guaranteed, or am I relying on an implementation detail here? 
    std::numeric_limits<S>::max();                // Prints 'got called'
    std::numeric_limits<const S>::max();          // Prints 'got called'
    std::numeric_limits<volatile S>::max();       // Prints 'got called'
    std::numeric_limits<const volatile S>::max(); // Prints 'got called'
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this applies to specializations or not but I think the compiler are implementing [this paragraph](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/numeric.limits#general-5) for all specializations, not just those built int.

Comment: It might be a good idea to add `static_assert(std::numeric_limits<...>::is_specialized);` to make sure a specialization exists.

Comment: "MSCV" - do you mean "MSVC"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's guaranteed since [LWG559](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue559) which dealt with this specifically by requiring that

- *The value of each member of a `numeric_limits` specialization on a cv-qualified `T` is equal to the value of the same member of `numeric_limits<T>`.*

The proposed (and implemented) resolution was:

- *Add to the synopsis of the `<limits>` header, immediately below the declaration of the primary template, the following:*

  ```cpp
  template <class T> class numeric_limits<const T>;
  template <class T> class numeric_limits<volatile T>;
  template <class T> class numeric_limits<const volatile T>;
  ```

  These are for example implemented in gcc as such:

  ```cpp
  template<typename _Tp>
    struct numeric_limits<const _Tp>
    : public numeric_limits<_Tp> { };

  template<typename _Tp>
    struct numeric_limits<volatile _Tp>
    : public numeric_limits<_Tp> { };

  template<typename _Tp>
    struct numeric_limits<const volatile _Tp>
    : public numeric_limits<_Tp> { };
  ```

The LWG issue also has an informal note at the bottom:

- *[ Portland: Martin will clarify that user-defined types get cv-specializations automatically. ]*

---

You can see that the addition to the standard works as intended by implementing a similar type, here called `foo`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// STD
template<class T>
struct foo {
    inline static constexpr bool is_S = false;
};

template <class T> struct foo<const T> : foo<T> {};
template <class T> struct foo<volatile T> : foo<T> {};
template <class T> struct foo<const volatile T> : foo<T> {};
```

Now add a type, `S`, and a specialization for `foo<S>` only:

```cpp
// User-defined type and foo specialization:

struct S {};

template<>
struct foo<S> {
    inline static constexpr bool is_S = true;
};
```

and `foo<const volatile S>` will pick the specialization:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << foo<const volatile S>::is_S << '\n'; // prints 1
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9jvMK7hrj)

Comment: But that doesn't answer OP's question, does it? That just says that all the CV-qualified versions need to be the same. It doesn't clarify whether the implementer is responsible for defining those variants.

For example, the OP could also declare:

    template<> struct numeric_limits<const S> : numeric_limits<S> {};
    // and the same for volatile and const volatile

The question is: is that necessary or not?

Comment: @MaksVerver https://eel.is/c++draft/limits.syn#header:%3climits%3e shows that `<limits>` includes a partial specialization for all cv qualified T to enforce this requirement (as suggested by the linked defect issue). So CV qualified specializations shouldn't need to be provided.

Comment: @MaksVerver Yes, what François' said. The LWG issue I linked to also contains the same tripplet as the proposed solution. I added that to the answer too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for clarifying but I don't think that settles it either. That definition only declares that the four variants exist, but it doesn't define them. Take a look at this: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/eMozEYqWr

The reason OP's code works is that <limits> includes a definition like template<typename T> struct numeric_limits<const T> : public numeric_limits<T {}; the question is if that's guaranteed by the standard, and from some quick Googling I couldn't confirm that it is.

Comment: @MaksVerver You need to read the LWG issue as a whole. It specifies that _The value of each member of a numeric_limits specialization on a cv-qualified T is equal to the value of the same member of numeric_limits<T>_ and it adds the tripplet to solve that, but as is very common, the _implementation_ of those are up to the library implementors to provide. They only need to make sure that they end up being equal to the non-cv qualified version. And yes, the reason it works is because of the definitions in `<limits>`. Your example is lacking the definitions so, of course it will not work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think we're talking past each other. I agree that the standard says that the specialization must be defined and the same for all four cv-qualified versions of a type. But the standard, as far as I can tell, doesn't say how that's accomplished.

The question is, those generic definitions in <limits> that infer the three cv-qualified versions from the non-cv-qualified version, are they required by standard? Or can a standard-compliant implementation just define e.g. four copies of each specialization and not include the generic definitions? That's the core of the issue.

Comment: @MaksVerver It doesn't matter. They can be four copies instead of inheriting from `numeric_limits<T>`. They only need to make sure that _"The value of each member of a `numeric_limits` specialization on a cv-qualified `T` is equal to the value of the same member of `numeric_limits<T>`"_. That's what the standard says.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I saw you updated your answer to cite an important note: “[ Portland: Martin will clarify that user-defined types get cv-specializations automatically. ]” That's the important part, especially the word *automatically*. Although it's not *technically* part of the C++ standard (yet), I think this settles the question in that the note makes it clear that the intent is to require the library implementations to provide the generic definition, so that user-defined types only need to include an explicit definition for the non-cv quantified version.

Comment: @MaksVerver Note that this issue has "CD1" status, which means that it was fixed in Committee Draft 1, which means it became official in C++11.

Comment: @MaksVerver Note also that according to [[contents]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/contents#1), the presence of e.g. `template <class T> class numeric_limits<const T>;` in the synopsis implies that the implementation actually provides the full definition for that particular partial specialization. The programmer doesn't provide the definition.